# Regex To Match specific pattern, yet exclude specific case

Tags: regex

I am struggling with this one, I have to match strings that end with `_ERROR`, yet I want to skip strings containing `SET_ERROR`

Here my best try so far: `/\w*(?!SET)_ERROR\b/`, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?!SET_ERROR\b)\w*_ERROR\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/laXSiD/1). It matches a word boundary (`\b`), then makes sure there is no whole word `SET_ERROR` immediately to the right of the current location (see the negative lookahead `(?!SET_ERROR\b)`), then consumes 0+ word chars and `_ERROR` followed with the trailing word boundary.

If you have a lookbehind support:

```
\w*_(?<!\bSET_)ERROR\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/laXSiD/2). Here, `\w*` consumes 0+ word chars, `_` is matched, and then `(?<!\bSET_)` negative lookbehind makes sure the word chars consumed before are not `SET_` (as a whole word). Then, `ERROR\b` matches a whole word `ERROR`.